# Google Tasks Api - Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-tasks-api

I've written the below code to create a task whenever a new item is added to a collection in the firestore.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

const { CloudTasksClient } = require('@google-cloud/tasks')

exports.moveActivityFromPlanToRecord = () =>
    functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .firestore.document('Users/{userId}/Activities/{activityId}')
        .onCreate(async snapshot => {

            const moveTime = snapshot.data()! as MoveTime

            if (!moveTime || !moveTime.dueTime) {
                console.log("DueTime is empty or null: \n" + moveTime)
                return
            }


            // Get the project ID from the FIREBASE_CONFIG env var
            const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG!).projectId
            const location = 'europe-west1'
            const queue = 'activityDateEventChecker'

            //queuePath is going to be a string that uniquely identifes the task
            const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient()
            const queuePath: string =
                tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue)

            // URL to my callback function and the contents of the payload to deliver
            const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/activityDateEventCheckerCallback`
            const docPath = snapshot.ref.path
            const dueTime = moveTime.dueTime
            const payload: MoveTaskPayload = { docPath, dueTime }

            console.log(payload)

            // build up the configuration for the Cloud Task
            const task = {
                httpRequest: {
                    httpMethod: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64'),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                },
                scheduleTime: {
                    seconds: moveTime.dueTime / 1000
                }
            }

            // enqueue the task in the queue
            return tasksClient.createTask({ parent: queuePath, task: task })
        })


interface MoveTime extends admin.firestore.DocumentData {
    dueTime?: number
}
interface MoveTaskPayload {
    docPath: string,
    dueTime: number
}
```

When the function is triggered (when a new "activity" is added to the collection), it throws the following error:

> Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument

What could be the problem here? 
BTW, should the last line in the method `return` the task, or `await` it?

---

**EDIT**: The exact same code is now working without me changing anything! I just deployed it with the Termux app just for fun, and after that it started working!

Comment: share the complete logs and the line on which error occurs, is it the post method or before it?

Comment: Did you find out what was going wrong ? I'm getting the same error. The stack trace involve GRPC. I was thinking it's mabye related to this : body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(payload)).toString('base64')

but I've no clue...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your current issue stems from:
`exports.moveActivityFromPlanToRecord = () => ...

If you remove the `() =>` part then when the  `moveActivityFromPlanToRecord` function is called, the expected parameters will need to match what `onCreate()` expects.

That shouldn't solve everything for you because `onCreate()` takes two parameters, `function onCreate(snapshot: DataSnapshot, context: EventContext): PromiseLike<any> | any` (took that from the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#oncreate) rather than source code because I'm on mobile). Which means that there is no way for the `onCreate()` function to receive parameters in your current implementation.

> What could be the problem here? \ BTW, should the last line in the method return the task, or await it?
> Almost certain that you need to return a `Promise` or `String`. That's a basic understanding you should read about for all background Google Cloud functions.

There may be other issues, but that should help resolve what your asking for.